# Smarty template inheritance only provides local scope variables?

Tags: smarty, scope

Using the latest version of Smarty 3 with template inheritance I'd like to set a variable in a child template and use it in the parent:

list.tpl

```
{extends file="page.tpl"}

{block name="head"}
    {$page_var = array("abc", "xyz")}
{/block}

{block name="content"}
    <div>...</div>
{/block}
```

page.tpl

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    {block name="head"}
        {$page_var = array()}
    {/block}

    {mytemplatefunc foo=array("bar") + $page_var}
    ...
```

The main page template initializes a variable and the child page sets the variable if needed.  The main page template would then use that variable when calling a template function.  But `$page_var` is always empty.  **It's as if the scope of the template variables are always local. Is going back to `{include}` the only solution?**

I've tried `{assign scope='global'}` and `{assign scope='parent'}` even though they are intended for includes. I also tried using my own static class methods and variables (to hang onto the value) but it never works.  And elsewhere it's been suggested trying to use variables outside of `{block}` but that goes directly against the documentation.

Comment: are you sure that expressions are allowed for default-values: `{templatefunc param=array("def") + $page_var}`

Comment: Yes, as long as `$page_var` is defined there is no error.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you redefine $page_var in the Template Extension (list.tpl)?

Have you tried adding values to the original $page_var instead?

So instead of

```
$page_var = array("abc", "xyz")
```

you could do

```
array_push($page_var, "abc", "xyz")
```

Comment: The head block in page.tpl doesn't run if you have a head block in list.tpl, so I get `array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array`.